# Accidentally rebased only one of my change sets

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I had 3 change sets that I wanted to rebase on top of the latest revisions. Unfortunately, I selected only one of them to be rebased and so this did a merge. Is there any way I can either undo the rebase or change it so the other two change sets get rebased as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the very last thing you did you can do a 'hg rollback' which is a one-level undo.  If, however, you've done anything since that alters the repository state (push, pull, commit, etc.) then rollback won't help you.

If it's any consolation, merging is generally preferable to rebasing and a mercurial history with a lot of merges shows someone who is using mercurial to its fullest. :)

Comment: Since my changes just added new files, instead of modifying existing files, I thought it would be worthwhile rebasing instead of doing a branch and merge. I suppose that it doesn't really matter much anyway

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with rebasing, but for some reason some folks consider a linear history a "prettier" history, whereas I want a history that shows the real order in which things were done and sometimes that order is parallel.  If you really need to you can always `clone -r ` your repo up to the point where your repo diverged and then move of the changes you wish you were linear using export and import or the functionally identical transplant extension.  I'd just learn to live with the accurate history you have.

Comment: If you're going to claim that merging is preferable to rebasing, please support that with some proof.

Comment: It's not a thing you can prove, it's about what you want your history to represent.  Some people/projects want their history to show a steady flow toward the current state with each commit representing one logical change.  Some want their histories to show every wart and blind ally that was later removed, undone, or remerged.  Neither is right, but the Mercurial project itself is closer to the second.  They have a _very_ branch history and while individual devs may rebase, the project and primary author don't.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you haven't pushed it to another repo for others to grab, then you can put those changesets anywhere on the graph you want.  You can move changesets with  [hg rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) and prune changsets and their descendents with [hg strip](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip).

Both strip and rebase save "undo" information as [bundle](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LookingIntoBundles) files in your .hg/strip-backup/

Note that neither strip nor rebase are enabled by default with mercurial.  You need to enable them in the .hgrc file.